# Error with \hyperref and Custom Command in Theorem Environment

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, xparse, thmtools

I'm getting an "Undefined control sequence" error in Overleaf when using a custom command with \hyperref inside a theorem defined by amsthm, with thmtools and xparse for optional arguments. Simplified code:

latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, hyperref, thmtools, xparse}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LREc}{o}{\hyperref[rule:LREc]{\ensuremath{P \leftrightarrow Q, P \vdash Q}\IfValueT{#1}{(#1)}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\listoftheorems
\section{Introduction}
    \label{rule:LREc}
    \begin{theorem}[\LREc] \( P \leftrightarrow Q, Q \vdash P \) \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Error points to `\LREc` in the theorem. Any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: I get only an error from the missing \title and \author.

Comment: I checked the version on overleaf this code does not give an undefined error. show the full log of the run including the error message